# Start appium server from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, appium

So I try to Start `appium` server from `jenkins` pipeline:

```
APPIUM_PORT = '4723'

stage('Start appium server') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Start appium server on port ${APPIUM_PORT}"
                    sh "appium --port ${APPIUM_PORT}"
                }
            }
        }
```

I have `appium` command line on my machine and I can start the server using the command `appium`

And this fails without any errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this through a batch file, by invoking the batch file in your script